# XSLT Transformation does not work with a XML file that contains composed tags like <tag1:tag2> </tag1:tag2 > and some specific attributes

Tags: xml, xslt, namespaces

We are trying transforming an XML file that comes as result from a GetCapabilities operation on a WMS, but the composed name tags are throwing errors, more exactly the tags with a name that is composed by two words that are separated using a colon, as in the following sources:

1)

```
<OnlineResource xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="http://www.ign.es/wms-inspire/ign-base?SERVICE=WMS&"/>
```

2)

```
<OnlineResource xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="http://www.ign.es/wms-inspire/ign-base?SERVICE=WMS&"/>
```

3)

```
<inspire_vs:ExtendedCapabilities>
<inspire_common:MetadataUrl xsi:type="inspire_common:resourceLocatorType">
<inspire_common:URL>http://www.ign.es/csw-inspire/srv/es/csw?SERVICE=CSW&VERSION=2.0.2&REQUEST=GetRecordById&outputSchema=http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd&ElementSetName=full&ID=spaignwms_www.ign.es_wms-inspire_ignbase_2011</inspire_common:URL>
<inspire_common:MediaType>application/vnd.ogc.csw.GetRecordByIdResponse_xml
</inspire_common:MediaType>
</inspire_common:MetadataUrl>
<inspire_common:SupportedLanguages xsi:type="inspire_common:supportedLanguagesType">
<inspire_common:DefaultLanguage>
<inspire_common:Language>spa</inspire_common:Language>
</inspire_common:DefaultLanguage>
<inspire_common:SupportedLanguage>
<inspire_common:Language>eng
</inspire_common:Language>
</inspire_common:SupportedLanguage>
</inspire_common:SupportedLanguages>
<inspire_common:ResponseLanguage>
<inspire_common:Language>spa</inspire_common:Language>
</inspire_common:ResponseLanguage>
</inspire_vs:ExtendedCapabilities>
```

Also the attributes: xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wms", xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink", xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" which are contained into the tag , are avoiding  that it  works correctly:

```
<WMS_Capabilities srv="http://schemas.opengis.net/iso/19139/20060504/srv/srv.xsd" gmd="http://schemas.opengis.net/iso/19139/20060504/gmd/gmd.xsd" gco="http://schemas.opengis.net/iso/19139/20060504/gco/gco.xsd" inspire_vs="http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/inspire_vs/1.0" gml="http://schemas.opengis.net/gml" inspire_common="http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/common/1.0" version="1.3.0" updateSequence="2619" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wms" xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wms http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/inspire_vs/1.0/inspire_vs.xsd">
```

For now the only way to make the transformation works has been editing the original XML to take away that conflictive parts, a solution which does not have much sense, so any idea to solve this inconvenient is welcome

Here is a simple XSL file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Get Capabilities Operation:</h1>
    <table border="1">
    <tr>
    <td> <xsl:value-of select="WMS_Capabilities/Service/Title"/> 
        <!--  it is not able to take the content that is within the label "Title"-->
    </td> 
    </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is a part of XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="ign-base.xsl"?>

<WMS_Capabilities xmlns:srv="http://schemas.opengis.net/iso/19139/20060504/srv/srv.xsd" 
xmlns:gmd="http://schemas.opengis.net/iso/19139/20060504/gmd/gmd.xsd" 
xmlns:gco="http://schemas.opengis.net/iso/19139/20060504/gco/gco.xsd" 
xmlns:inspire_vs="http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/inspire_vs/1.0" 
xmlns:gml="http://schemas.opengis.net/gml" 
xmlns:inspire_common="http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/common/1.0" 
version="1.3.0" updateSequence="2619" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wms" 
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wms http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/inspire_vs/1.0/inspire_vs.xsd">  
  <Service>
    <Name>WMS</Name>
    <Title>Mapa base de España del Instituto Geográfico Nacional</Title>
    <Abstract>Servicio Web de Mapas conforme al perfil INSPIRE de ISO19128-WMS 1.3.0 que permite acceder a cartografía procedente de diversas bases de datos geográficos del  IGN España. Para escalas pequeñas se usa la Base Cartográfica Numérica 1:200.000 (BCN200) y datos estructurados procedentes del  SIGNA (Sistema de Información Geográfica NAcional); para escalas intermedias se usa la Base Topográfica Nacional 1:25.000 (BTN25) junto con la Base Cartográfica Numérica 1:25.000 (BCN25); para escalas grandes, información procedente del callejero oficial Cartociudad. Se muestra información geográfica perteneciente a los siguientes anexos de Inspire: 1) Nombres geográficos, Unidades administrativas, Direcciones, Redes de transporte, Hidrografía, Lugares protegidos (pertenecientes al Anexo I);  2) Elevaciones y Cubierta terrestre (pertenecientes al Anexo II); 3) Edificios, Servicios de utilidad pública y estatales, Instalaciones de producción e industriales e Instalaciones agrícolas y de acuicultura (pertenecientes al Anexo III). También se muestra información que bien por los tipos de objetos espaciales o la geometría que se utiliza para representarlos están fuera de Inspire. Son los siguientes: Paises, Fondo cartográfico, Manazanas urbanas, Aeropuertos y las capas contenidas en los grupos de capas Puertos, Islas y Sombreado. El resto de capas se han agrupado constituyendo grupos de capas equivalentes a capas Inspire cuya denominación es conforme con la Directiva INSPIRE 2007/2/EC (nombre, título y estilo Inspire por defecto). Todas las capas tienen asociado un estilo de visualización definido por el IGN y además, si pertenece a Inspire, el estilo Inspire por defecto.</Abstract>
    <KeywordList>
      <Keyword>WMS</Keyword>
      <Keyword>IDEE</Keyword>
      <Keyword>BCN200</Keyword>
      <Keyword>BCN25</Keyword>
      <Keyword>BTN25</Keyword>
      <Keyword>Cartografía</Keyword>
      <Keyword vocabulary="ISO 19119 geographic services taxonomy, version 2.3">infoMapAccessService</Keyword>
      <Keyword vocabulary="ISO 19119 geographic services taxonomy, version 2.3">infoManagementService</Keyword>
      <Keyword>España</Keyword>
      <Keyword>SIGNA</Keyword>
      <Keyword>Topográfico</Keyword>
      <Keyword>View</Keyword>
      <Keyword>WMS 1.3.0</Keyword>
      <Keyword>OGC</Keyword>
    </KeywordList>
    <OnlineResource xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="http://www.ign.es"/>
    <ContactInformation>
      <ContactPersonPrimary>
        <ContactPerson/>
        <ContactOrganization>Instituto Geográfico Nacional</ContactOrganization>
      </ContactPersonPrimary>
      <ContactPosition>PointOfContact</ContactPosition>
      <ContactAddress>
        <AddressType>Postal</AddressType>
        <Address>General Ibáñez de Íbero, 3</Address>
        <City>Madrid</City>
        <StateOrProvince>España</StateOrProvince>
        <PostCode>28003</PostCode>
        <Country>España</Country>
      </ContactAddress>
      <ContactVoiceTelephone>+34 91 597 96 61</ContactVoiceTelephone>
      <ContactFacsimileTelephone>+34 91 597 97 64</ContactFacsimileTelephone>
      <ContactElectronicMailAddress>ign@fomento.es</ContactElectronicMailAddress>
    </ContactInformation>
    <Fees>no conditions apply</Fees>
    <AccessConstraints>licencia</AccessConstraints>
  </Service>
  <Capability>
    <Request>
      <GetCapabilities>
        <Format>text/xml</Format>
        <DCPType>
          <HTTP>
            <Get>
              <OnlineResource xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="http://www.ign.es/wms-inspire/ign-base?SERVICE=WMS&amp;"/>
            </Get>
            <Post>
              <OnlineResource xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="http://www.ign.es/wms-inspire/ign-base?SERVICE=WMS&amp;"/>
            </Post>
          </HTTP>
        </DCPType>
      </GetCapabilities>
      <GetMap>
        <Format>image/png</Format>
        <Format>application/atom+xml</Format>
        <Format>application/pdf</Format>
        <Format>application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml</Format>
        <Format>application/vnd.google-earth.kmz</Format>
        <Format>image/gif</Format>
        <Format>image/jpeg</Format>
        <Format>image/svg+xml</Format>
        <Format>image/tiff</Format>
        <DCPType>
          <HTTP>
            <Get>
              <OnlineResource xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="http://www.ign.es/wms-inspire/ign-base?SERVICE=WMS&amp;"/>
            </Get>
          </HTTP>
        </DCPType>
      </GetMap>
      <GetFeatureInfo>
        <Format>text/html</Format>
        <DCPType>
          <HTTP>
            <Get>
              <OnlineResource xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="http://www.ign.es/wms-inspire/ign-base?SERVICE=WMS&amp;"/>
            </Get>
            <Post>
              <OnlineResource xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="http://www.ign.es/wms-inspire/ign-base?SERVICE=WMS&amp;"/>
            </Post>
          </HTTP>
        </DCPType>
      </GetFeatureInfo>
    </Request>
    <Exception>
      <Format>XML</Format>
      <Format>INIMAGE</Format>
      <Format>BLANK</Format>
    </Exception>
    <inspire_vs:ExtendedCapabilities>
      <inspire_common:MetadataUrl xsi:type="inspire_common:resourceLocatorType">
        <inspire_common:URL>http://www.ign.es/csw-inspire/srv/es/csw?SERVICE=CSW&amp;VERSION=2.0.2&amp;REQUEST=GetRecordById&amp;outputSchema=http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd&amp;ElementSetName=full&amp;ID=spaignwms_www.ign.es_wms-inspire_ignbase_2011</inspire_common:URL>
        <inspire_common:MediaType>application/vnd.ogc.csw.GetRecordByIdResponse_xml</inspire_common:MediaType>
      </inspire_common:MetadataUrl>
      <inspire_common:SupportedLanguages xsi:type="inspire_common:supportedLanguagesType">
        <inspire_common:DefaultLanguage>
          <inspire_common:Language>spa</inspire_common:Language>
        </inspire_common:DefaultLanguage>
        <inspire_common:SupportedLanguage>
          <inspire_common:Language>eng</inspire_common:Language>
        </inspire_common:SupportedLanguage>
      </inspire_common:SupportedLanguages>
      <inspire_common:ResponseLanguage>
        <inspire_common:Language>spa</inspire_common:Language>
      </inspire_common:ResponseLanguage>
    </inspire_vs:ExtendedCapabilities>
    <Layer>
      <Title>Mapa base de España del Instituto Geográfico Nacional</Title>
      <Abstract>Servicio Web de Mapas conforme al perfil INSPIRE de ISO19128-WMS 1.3.0 que permite acceder a cartografía procedente de diversas bases de datos geográficos del  IGN España. Para escalas pequeñas se usa la Base Cartográfica Numérica 1:200.000 (BCN200) y datos estructurados procedentes del  SIGNA (Sistema de Información Geográfica NAcional); para escalas intermedias se usa la Base Topográfica Nacional 1:25.000 (BTN25) junto con la Base Cartográfica Numérica 1:25.000 (BCN25); para escalas grandes, información procedente del callejero oficial Cartociudad. Se muestra información geográfica perteneciente a los siguientes anexos de Inspire: 1) Nombres geográficos, Unidades administrativas, Direcciones, Redes de transporte, Hidrografía, Lugares protegidos (pertenecientes al Anexo I);  2) Elevaciones y Cubierta terrestre (pertenecientes al Anexo II); 3) Edificios, Servicios de utilidad pública y estatales, Instalaciones de producción e industriales e Instalaciones agrícolas y de acuicultura (pertenecientes al Anexo III). También se muestra información que bien por los tipos de objetos espaciales o la geometría que se utiliza para representarlos están fuera de Inspire. Son los siguientes: Paises, Fondo cartográfico, Manazanas urbanas, Aeropuertos y las capas contenidas en los grupos de capas Puertos, Islas  y Sombreado. El resto de capas se han agrupado constituyendo grupos de capas equivalentes a capas Inspire cuya denominación es conforme con la Directiva INSPIRE 2007/2/EC (nombre, título y estilo Inspire por defecto). Todas las capas tienen asociado un estilo de visualización definido por el IGN y además, si pertenece a Inspire, el estilo Inspire por defecto.</Abstract>
      <CRS>EPSG:4258</CRS>
      <CRS>EPSG:4326</CRS>
      <CRS>CRS:84</CRS>
      <CRS>EPSG:23029</CRS>
      <CRS>EPSG:23030</CRS>
      <CRS>EPSG:23031</CRS>
      <CRS>EPSG:25828</CRS>
      <CRS>EPSG:25829</CRS>
      <CRS>EPSG:25830</CRS>
      <CRS>EPSG:25831</CRS>
      <CRS>EPSG:4230</CRS>
      <EX_GeographicBoundingBox>
        <westBoundLongitude>-179.90</westBoundLongitude>
        <eastBoundLongitude>179.90</eastBoundLongitude>
        <southBoundLatitude>-89.90</southBoundLatitude>
        <northBoundLatitude>84.00</northBoundLatitude>
      </EX_GeographicBoundingBox>
      <Layer>
        <Name>GN.GeographicalNames</Name>
        <Title>Nombres geográficos</Title>
        <Abstract>Representación de datos espaciales correspondientes al tema "Nombres Geográficos" del Anexo I de la directiva INSPIRE.</Abstract>
        <CRS>EPSG:23029</CRS>
          <CRS>EPSG:23030</CRS>
          <CRS>EPSG:23031</CRS>
          <CRS>EPSG:25828</CRS>
          <CRS>EPSG:25829</CRS>
          <CRS>EPSG:25830</CRS>
          <CRS>EPSG:25831</CRS>
          <CRS>EPSG:4230</CRS>
          <EX_GeographicBoundingBox>
            <westBoundLongitude>-19.00</westBoundLongitude>
            <eastBoundLongitude>5.00</eastBoundLongitude>
            <southBoundLatitude>27.00</southBoundLatitude>
            <northBoundLatitude>44.00</northBoundLatitude>
          </EX_GeographicBoundingBox>
```

And a link to the services with the full XML answer

http://www.ign.es/wms-inspire/ign-base?request=GetCapabilities&service=WMS

Thanks in advance

Comment: Those are called "namespaces" and are one of the more difficult aspects of XSL until you understand how they work (which is somewhat complex).  Read up about namespace handling in XML and XSL.

Comment: Thanks Jim, I have looking around for the W3C standars and recomendations, specialy the XSLT recomendation in http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt , but I have not found yet the namespace documetation that you have made reference, do you know about a most specific doc where I should look for in order to solve my issue

Comment: By the way, I have found these 2 references:
http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/ and
http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/#sec-namespaces 
A most recent recommendation of XSLT (2.0) that includes some new topics than recommendation 1.0 does not, and the Recommendation about Namespaces in XML 1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not show the Xml document that contains WMS_Capabilities et al. If Service and Title are in the same namespace something like this should help:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ns=""http://www.opengis.net/wms"">

<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Get Capabilities Operation:</h1>
    <table border="1">
    <tr>
    <td> <xsl:value-of select="ns:WMS_Capabilities/ns:Service/ns:Title"/> 
        <!--  it is not able to take the content that is within the label "Title"-->
    </td> 
    </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I linked the namespace-uri with "ns" prefix and used the prefix in the XPath expression to indicate that the elements belong to the namespace the prefix is associated with.

Comment: Thanks Pawel, I have included a part of the XML and a link to the service which returns it in case you need see it completely. 

On the other hand, can you please indicate to me for this special case why  you have chose http://www.opengis.net/wms between all the rest of possibilities that are into the tag's attributes?  is it because it is the only one with the xmlns single name? what about the rest of possibilities that have  combinations as:  xmlns:gmd, xmlns:gco, xmlns:inspire_vs, xmlns:gml, xmlns:inspire_common, xmlns:xlink, xmlns:xsi?

Comment: xmlns:aa="uri" binds namespace uri to the aa prefix but does not put the element in the namespace. if a prefix is bound to a namespace you can use {prefix}:{elementName} syntax (e.g. aa:element) to say that the element belongs to the namespace. It allows mixing element in multiple namespaces. In case of attributes this is the only way to tell that the attribute belong to a namespace. if there is xmlns attribute on an element it means that the element and all children (unless redefined) belong to the namespace whose uri is the value of xmlns attribute.